# How to add padding around to grid of squares?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a grid of squares using `D3`.  My code works, but I'd like to add some padding around each of the squares so that the grid does not look so "tight".

Here is my code:

```
    class Matrix {

    constructor(parentElement, data1, data2, data3) {
        this.parentElement = parentElement;
        this.data1 = data1;
        this.data2 = data2;
        this.data3 = data3;

        this.cellHeight = 40;
        this.cellWidth = 40;

        this.initializeVisual()

    }


    initializeVisual() {
        let vis = this;

        vis.margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40};
        vis.width = document.getElementById(vis.parentElement).getBoundingClientRect().width - vis.margin.left - vis.margin.right;

        vis.height = 800 - vis.margin.top - vis.margin.bottom;

        // init drawing area
        vis.svg = d3.select('#' + vis.parentElement).append('svg')
            .attr('width', vis.width + vis.margin.left + vis.margin.right)
            .attr('height', vis.height + vis.margin.top + vis.margin.bottom)
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', `translate (${vis.margin.left}, ${vis.margin.top})`);


        // Draws the initial grid

        let squaresPerRow = 16

        let scale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, squaresPerRow -1])
            .range([0, this.cellWidth * squaresPerRow])

        vis.squares = vis.svg.selectAll('.squares')
            .data(d3.range(256))
            .enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr('x', (d, i) => {
                let n = i % squaresPerRow
                return scale(n)
            })
            .attr('y', (d, i) => {
                let n = Math.floor(i / 16)
                return scale(n)
            })
            .attr('width', this.cellWidth)
            .attr('height', this.cellHeight)
            .attr('fill', 'lightgrey');

}
```

The resulting grid looks like this:

[image]

How can I add the padding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd change the linear scale for a point scale, but here's a solution using most of your code as it is.

First, get rid of that minus one in the domain, that's a cumbersome way for creating the padding:

```
.domain([0, squaresPerRow -1])
```

Then, after you set the padding (here named `padding`), you can translate the `x` and `y` positions by half of it, and subtracting the rectangles' width and height by that padding.

Here's a demo, change the variable `padding` for different spaces:

```js
const svg = d3.select("div")
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 400)
  .attr('height', 400);

let squaresPerRow = 8,
  cellWidth = 40,
  cellHeight = 40,
  padding = 14;

let scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, squaresPerRow])
  .range([0, cellWidth * squaresPerRow])

const squares = svg.selectAll('.squares')
  .data(d3.range(squaresPerRow ** 2))
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', (d, i) => {
    let n = i % squaresPerRow
    return scale(n) + padding / 2
  })
  .attr('y', (d, i) => {
    let n = Math.floor(i / squaresPerRow)
    return scale(n) + padding / 2
  })
  .attr('width', cellWidth - padding)
  .attr('height', cellHeight - padding)
  .attr('fill', 'lightgrey');
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```